# Collision detection in a Java game

Tags: java

I am programming my first game in java for an High School Project and obviously I am encountering some problems.
My game is about Dragon Ball(so a fight game) and **I need help with the collision** of the two character. 
I have tried with the rectangles but it seems that the coordinates never change( hence the collision happen only on the start points).

This is the class that control the collision:

```
public class RettangoloC 
{

int X,Y,dy,dx;
Rectangle2D r1;
RettangoloV rettV;

public RettangoloC()
{

initRett();
}
```

These are the initial coordinates of the "Goku" Character;

```
 private void initRett() 
 {
 X = 950;
 Y = 0; 
 r1 =  new Rectangle(X,Y, 60,100);

}

 public void Move()
{
X += dx;
Y += dy;
 }
```

This is where the collision should be detected;

```
public boolean checkCollisions() {

rettV=new RettangoloV();
    if (r1.intersects(rettV.getRett())) 
    {
        return true;

    }
    else
        return false;
    }

 public Rectangle2D getRett()
{
  return r1;
 }
```

Every time the character is moving, the rectangle moves too;

```
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
   int key = e.getKeyCode();


if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) 
{
    dx = - 4;
}

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {

    dx = 4;
}

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
    dy = -2;
}

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
    dy = +1;
}

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD1) {

    dx-=1;

}

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2) {
    dx-=1;

}

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD3) {
    dx-=1;
}


}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

int key = e.getKeyCode();


if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
   dx = 0;
}

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {

   dx = 0;
}

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
    dy = 0;
}

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
    dy = 0;
}

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD1) {
    dx=0;

}

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD3) {
    dx=0;
}
}
}
```

The rectangle for the character "Vegeta" is almost the same, with different names for the variables.

```
public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public Image getImage() {
    return imageT;
}

public void setImage()
{

    if(a==1)
    {
        imageT=image2;
    }
    if(a==0)
    {   

        imageT=image1;
    }
    if(a==2)
    {
        imageT=image3;

    }

    if(a==4)
    {
    imageT=image4;

    }
    if(a==3)
    {
        imageT=image3r;
    }
    if(a==6)
    {
        imageT=image2r;
    }
    if(a==7)
    {
        imageT=image4r;
    }
}
```

With "a" the image of Goku will change;

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    rett=new RettangoloC();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) 
    {
        tx=getX();

        if(tx<=0) //Blocco
        {
            dx=0;
        }
        else
        {
            if(tx<=0)
            {
                dx=0;
            }
            else
        dx = - 4;
        }

        a=2;
        setImage();
        getImage();

    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        tx=getX();

        if(tx>=950)
        {
            dx=0;
        }
        else
        {
            if(tx>=950)
            {
                dx=0;
            }
            else
        dx = 4;
        }
        a=1;
        setImage();
        getImage();
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        ty=getY();
        if(ty<=4)
        {
            dy=-0;
        }
        else
        {
            if(ty<=2)
            {
                dy=-0;
            }
            else
        dy = -2;
        }
        a=4;
        setImage();
        getImage();
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        ty=getY();
        if(ty>=650)
        {
            dy=-0;
        }
        else
        {
            if(ty>=600)
            {
                dy=-0;
            }
            else
        dy = +1;
        }
        a=4;
        setImage();
        getImage();
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0) {
        a=10;
        setImage();
        getImage();
    }
```

The numbers are the attacks. I have tried the collision only with NUMPAD1;

```
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD1) {
        if(b1==true)
        {
            a=3;
        }
        else
        a=0;

        x-=1;
        setImage();
        getImage();
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2) {
        a=6;
        x-=1;
        setImage();
        getImage();
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD3) {
        a=7;
        x-=1;
        setImage();
        getImage();
    }


}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    a=0;


    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
       dx = 0;

        setImage();
        getImage();
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {

       dx = 0;
        a=0;
        setImage();
        getImage();
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        dy = 0;
        a=0;
        setImage();
        getImage();
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        dy = 0;
        a=0;
        setImage();
        getImage();
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD1) {
        a=0;
        setImage();
        getImage();

    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD3) {
        a=0;
        setImage();
        getImage();
    }
}
```

And then there is the class that manages all the others;

```
  private void initBoard() {

    addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
    setFocusable(true);

    sfondo=new Sfondo();
    craft = new Craft();
    vegeta= new Vegeta();
    rettc=new RettangoloC();
    rettv=new RettangoloV();

    timer1 = new Timer(DELAY,new Somma());
    timer1.start();
    timer2 = new Timer(DELAY,new Meno());
    timer2.start(); 
    timer3 = new Timer(DELAY,new RettCraft());
    timer3.start(); 
    timer4 = new Timer(DELAY,new RettVeg());
    timer4.start(); 
}



public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    doDrawing(g);

    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
}

private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2s = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2s.drawImage(sfondo.getSfondo(),sfondo.getXS(), sfondo.getYS(), this);

    Graphics2D g2g = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2g.drawImage(craft.getImage(),craft.getX(), craft.getY(), this);

    Graphics2D g2v = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2v.drawImage(vegeta.getImage2(),vegeta.getX2(), vegeta.getY2(), this); 
}



   class Somma implements ActionListener
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        craft.move();
        craft.setImage();
        craft.getImage();

        repaint(); 
    }
}

   class Meno implements ActionListener
   {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {    vegeta.move2();
        vegeta.setImage2();
        vegeta.getImage2();


        repaint(); 
     }
   }
```

class RettCraft implements ActionListener
    {

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
     rettc.Move();  
     craft.b1=rettc.checkCollisions();
}
}

   class RettVeg implements ActionListener
   {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
      {
     rettv.Move();  
     vegeta.b1=rettv.checkCollisions();
      }
    }

private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        craft.keyReleased(e);
        vegeta.keyReleased(e);
        rettc.keyReleased(e);
        rettv.keyReleased(e);

    }


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        craft.keyPressed(e);
        vegeta.keyPressed(e);
        rettc.keyReleased(e);
        rettv.keyReleased(e);
    }

    }




}
```

I know it is a lot of code, and also I am aware that the code in not well written, but I will "clear" it when the project is done. 
Thanks in advance ( if there is something wrong in the post please feel free to tell me, it is the first time that I use SOF).

Comment: "I know it is a lot of code" It's too much code to expect us to read to find where your problem is. Try to pin down where the problem is in your code, and post a [mcve].

Comment: In your `keyPressed()` method, you check for `if (tx <= 0)`, and then you check for the exact same condition again in the `else` branch.

Comment: By `dy = +1`, do you mean `dy += 1`? As it is, the `+` is redundant.